# Will i lose my files while upgrading to windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I'm just about to upgrade my **Windows 7** to **Windows 10**, And i'm wondering if i'm gonna **lose any data** from my **C drive**, or anything else from my **hard drive**.

Thank you.

Comment: Always have a second copy of important data stored elsewhere..

Answer (score 2):

Normally it should keep all your files on your harddrive, but as with any major change on your computer, it never hurts to make an off-site backup. If for whatever reason the upgrade fails and you have to reformat your disk, then at least you have your backup to restore.

If all goes well, you will have a clean profile and you will likely have to reinstall programs, but if there is sufficient space on the C drive, everything that windows did not keep will be moved to C:\Windows.old.

Comment: OK, Thank you.
And what about the shortcut that are in the desktop?

Comment: The C:\Users\username folder, will partially be migrated. If it does not move the shortcuts to your new desktop, they will be moved to c:\windows.old\users\username\desktop instead. Microsoft will not remove files.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark the answer as solved if this is the case. That way others know you no longer need help.